# Prevent foreman to crash when typo in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I am using foreman gem on my Rails project to handle the different processes to be launched at startup (web, mailer, delayed job, ...).

It's working as expected but if I save a file with a typo or try to access a property on a nil object, foreman crash for all processes. I have to manually kill each ruby and node (for maildev) processes in order to run `foreman start` again.

Is there a way to prevent foreman to crash as the [plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) plugin for gulp tasks ?

Thanks !

**My project**:

- Rails 4.2
- Ruby 2.2.0
- Foreman
- Server Unicorn
- Mac OSX

Comment: There's really not a lot of information to go on here.  What's the error when foreman crashes?  Does it have a stacktrace?  What's at the line which throws the error?

Comment: I don't think giving the trace is relevant: the crash can happen for any typo like a missing `end` closure for a block or trying to use a property for a nil object. The error message could be something like that: `rake aborted! syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end` (a classic rails error).

Comment: But do you really want foreman to swallow a syntax error?

Comment: I figured out delayed_job process was the guilty one. Still don't know how to prevent the bug.